# Spring MVC and JAVA applet

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, applet, classnotfoundexception

I am trying to create a Spring MVC project. I am also using Hibernate as ORM. I'm trying to put my applet.jar(wich I have used in several projects including a ASP.NET project) into my view. But every time I get the `ClassNotFoundException`. I tried many answers on stackoverflow but none have solved my issue. Since I'm new to Spring MVC, I'm wondering if I'm doing something wrong with the configuration. This is my project tree(image below)

[image: Project tree]

I've tried putting in two of my applets and have highlighted them. Now I'm putting these lines in my project:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>

<%
    String contextRoot = request.getContextPath() + "/";
    String resourceRoot = contextRoot + "resource/";
%>

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<h3>Business Form</h3>

<div id="wrapper">
    <form:form  action="rest/businessSaloon" method="post"  commandName="businessSaloon" id="businessSaloon">

        // some form data


    </form:form>

</div>


</body>
</html>

 <APPLET code="hr.niko.as.client.WorkstationApplet.class" 
        archive="<%=contextRoot %>resources/lib/WorkStationApplet460.jar"
        width=350 height=200>
</APPLET>

 <APPLET code="hr.niko.as.client.WorkstationApplet.class" 
        archive="<%=contextRoot %>resources/lib/WorkStationApplet460.jar"
        width=350 height=250>
</APPLET>

 <APPLET code="hr.niko.as.client.WorkstationApplet.class" 
        archive="<%=contextRoot %>resources/lib/WorkStationApplet807.jar"
        width=350 height=200>
</APPLET>

 <APPLET code="hr.niko.as.client.WorkstationApplet.class" 
        archive="<%=contextRoot %>resources/lib/WorkStationApplet807.jar"
        width=350 height=250>
</APPLET>
```

I've tried many ways but I get this error:

```
cache: Initialize resource manager: com.sun.deploy.cache.ResourceProviderImpl@9220cb basic: Added progress listener: sun.plugin.util.ProgressMonitorAdapter@1a60b26 basic: Plugin2ClassLoader.addURL parent called for http://localhost:8080/SpringMVCExample2/rest/businessSaloon/WorkStationApplet460.jar network: Cache entry not found [url: http://localhost:8080/SpringMVCExample2/rest/businessSaloon/WorkStationApplet460.jar, version: null]
```

Do I have to add the applet into the web.xml as a servlet with path description? If yes, how do I do that?

I appreciate any help!

Thanks!

EDIT:
Here is the complete error again with all four applet insertion attempts.

```
basic: Added progress listener: sun.plugin.util.ProgressMonitorAdapter@30b878
basic: Added progress listener: sun.plugin.util.ProgressMonitorAdapter@1beb87c
basic: Added progress listener: sun.plugin.util.ProgressMonitorAdapter@105e45c
basic: Added progress listener: sun.plugin.util.ProgressMonitorAdapter@bc7c8e
basic: Plugin2ClassLoader.addURL parent called for http://localhost:8080/SpringMVCExample2/rest/businessSaloon/WorkStationApplet807.jar
basic: Plugin2ClassLoader.addURL parent called for http://localhost:8080/SpringMVCExample2/WorkStationApplet807.jar
basic: Plugin2ClassLoader.addURL parent called for http://localhost:8080/SpringMVCExample2/rest/businessSaloon/WorkStationApplet460.jar
basic: Plugin2ClassLoader.addURL parent called for http://localhost:8080/SpringMVCExample2/WorkStationApplet460.jar
network: Cache entry not found [url: http://localhost:8080/SpringMVCExample2/WorkStationApplet460.jar, version: null]
network: Cache entry not found [url: http://localhost:8080/SpringMVCExample2/rest/businessSaloon/WorkStationApplet460.jar, version: null]
network: Cache entry not found [url: http://localhost:8080/SpringMVCExample2/rest/businessSaloon/WorkStationApplet807.jar, version: null]
network: Cache entry not found [url: http://localhost:8080/SpringMVCExample2/WorkStationApplet807.jar, version: null]
```

EDIT 2:
My path dispatcher path is here:

```
<servlet> 
<servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name> 
<servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-clas‌​s> <init-param> 
<param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name> <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value> </init-param> <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup> </servlet> 
<servlet-mapping> 
<servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name> 
<url-pattern>/</url-pattern> 
</servlet-mapping>
```

EDIT 3:
Here is my configuration file

```
package com.wargog.as;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class MvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }


}
```

Comment: JAR files, in web applications **must be found inside** the `WEB-INF/lib` directory. Generate the WAR file and check (using a Zip program) whether the JARs are found inside the `WEB-INF/lib` folder in the WAR file.

Comment: Hi! I just checked and the files are there in SpringMVCExample2\WEB-INF\lib\ after I put them in the project in that folder and exported the .war file.

Comment: @BuhakeSindi that's wrong. jars must be put in WEB-INF/lib to be in the classpath of the web application. This jar is the jar of an applet, that must be downloaded and executed in the browser. It's thus similar to an image, a JavaScript file or a CSS file.

Comment: @iPhoneNoob: the jar file is located in `<contextPath>/resources/lib`. But none of your 4 attempts uses this path. We also don't know how you configured Spring MVC. To what URL is the dispatcher servlet mapped?

Comment: @JB Nizet, Sorry, I misread the OPs post.

Comment: Don't post code in comments. Edit your question.

Comment: And read http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-config-static-resources

Comment: @JBNizet I tried what you suggested but I still get the same **classNotFoundException**. And I read the article. It's good for future reference. I can't still get it to work now...

Comment: So, you have configures Spring to serve resources, as indicated in the documentation? Where's your config?

Comment: Hi @JBNizet, sorry for the late response. I've updated my question with the config file but I still get the applet errors as before. Should I change something in my config file?